# Changed exif data does not get written to new file

Tags: php, laravel, exif

i'm currently trying to dynamically add exifdata to images on a laravel project.

I got the following code which causes 0 errors and creates a second image named test.jpg like it supposed to

```
    $imagePath = public_path('images/' . $request['filename']);
    $iptcData = iptcparse(file_get_contents($imagePath));

    $iptcData['2#120'][0] = 'this is  a comment';

    $newData = iptcembed(serialize($iptcData), $imagePath);
    $editedImagePath = public_path('images/test.jpg');
    if (file_put_contents($editedImagePath, $newData) === false) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Failed to update'], 500);
    }
```

but after checking with windows explorer, online exif tools or even with exif_read_data() there is no comment/s field set inside the exif data.

[image]

Things I have tried so far:

- writing different fields (regarding to php.net 120 IPTC_CAPTION is defined as
  IPTC_CAPTION)
- A 1 to 1 copy of the example code given on php.net
- multiple different libs but couldn't get any of them to work in my
  project.

Does anybody know a way to do this with php 8.2 and laravel 10?

Edit:
For testing purposes I changed the code back to the example looking like this again now:

```
public function showWithMetadata(Request $request)
{
    $imagePath = public_path('images/' . $request['filename']);

    $iptc = array(
        '2#120' => 'Test image',
        '2#116' => 'Copyright 2008-2009, The PHP Group'
    );

    $data = '';

    foreach($iptc as $tag => $string)
    {
        $tag = substr($tag, 2);
        $data .= $this->iptc_make_tag(2, $tag, $string);
    }

    $content = iptcembed($data, $imagePath);


    $fp = fopen($imagePath, "wb");
    fwrite($fp, $content);
    fclose($fp);
    dd($content);
    $fileContents = file_get_contents($imagePath);
    $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg',
        'Content-Length' => strlen($fileContents),
    ];
    return response($fileContents, 200, $headers);
}

private function iptc_make_tag($rec, $data, $value)
{
    $length = strlen($value);
    $retval = chr(0x1C) . chr($rec) . chr($data);

    if($length < 0x8000)
    {
        $retval .= chr($length >> 8) .  chr($length & 0xFF);
    }
    else
    {
        $retval .= chr(0x80) .
            chr(0x04) .
            chr(($length >> 24) & 0xFF) .
            chr(($length >> 16) & 0xFF) .
            chr(($length >> 8) & 0xFF) .
            chr($length & 0xFF);
    }

    return $retval . $value;
}
```

Still resulting in no fields written

Comment: The example on the manual page may help - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iptcembed.php

Comment: Like i said i copied this one 1 to 1 with the same result and I'm out of ideads whats going on

Comment: We have to go by the code in your question. In it [serialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize) seems really out of place since it is specific to PHP itself. You will be better of with the function by Thies C. Arntzen which you've already tried.

Comment: I changed the code back to the example and added it to the post.

Comment: Your mistake is that you're talking about Exif when in fact you use [IPTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iptc+php) - both have nothing to do with each other and both can co-exist in one file.